# How to permute the arrays within a cell array without using loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a two arrays within a <1x2 cell>. I want to permute those arrays. Of course, I could use a loop to permute each one, but is there any way to do that task at once, without using loops?

Example:

```
>> whos('M')
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  M         1x2              9624  cell    

>> permute(M,p_matrix)
```

This does not permute the contents of the two arrays within M.

I could use something like:

```
>> for k=1:size(M,2), M{k} = permute(M{k},p_matrix); end
```

but I'd prefer not to use loops.

Thanks.

Comment: Do those two arrays have the same number of dimensions `ndims(M{1}) == ndims(M{2})`? If so, do they also have the same sizes? Are those arrays both numeric?

Comment: You don't want to use loops on a 1-by-2 array??? Why not?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, they have the same dimensions and they are numeric. The cell array usually is 1x2, but it could be 1xN, where N could be a vastly large number.

Comment: @Dan The cell array usually is 1x2, yes, but it could be 1xN, where N could be a vastly large number.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Really? I though one of the best points of MATLAB is its efficent use of vectorised operations without using loops.

Comment: What do you think the assembly code is doing when you add together two vectors of, say, 65,536 elements ?  The advantage of vectorised operations over loops is that Matlab is better able to optimise the former but something, somewhere, is looping.

Comment: @baister it just uses more efficient loops in lower level languages. But with the JIT compiler, loops in Matlab really aren't that slow anymore.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So your recommendation is to use that loop I was trying to avoid, is it?

Comment: @Dan So your recommendation is to use that loop I was trying to avoid, is it?

Comment: One more thing I asked was do they have same sizes for all numeric arrays in each cell, i.e. is `all(size(M{1}) == size(M{2}))`? For a `1 x N` cell array, that would translate to is `all(size(M{1}) == size(M{2}))`, `all(size(M{2}) == size(M{3}))` ... `all(size(M{N-1}) == size(M{N}))`?

Comment: @baister well I would start off using loops in this case until I was certain that loops were too slow and needed to be optimized

Comment: @Divakar Yes. They all have the same sizes, just like you are saying.

Comment: That's good! Here's the final check if you could do for me - Does this throw any error - `vertcat(M{:})`?

Comment: @Divakar No error. It works properly.

Comment: @baister In addition to what Divakar is probably about to post as an answer: why do you use a cell array if all (`N`-dimensional) arrays have the same sizes? You could use an `N+1`-dimensional array, which is more efficient than cell arrays

Comment: @LuisMendo Because this structure could store other kind of arrays. However, under some conditions, all arrays have the same sizes and under those conditions I need to permute those arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work -

```
num_cells = numel(M) %// Number of cells in input cell array
size_cell = size(M{1}) %// Get sizes

%// Get size of the numeric array that will hold all of the data from the 
%// input cell array with the second dimension representing the index of 
%// each cell from the input cell array
size_num_arr = [size_cell(1) num_cells size_cell(2:end)] 

%// Dimensions array for permuting with the numeric array holding all data
perm_dim = [1 3:numel(size_cell)+1 2]

%// Store data from input M into a vertically concatenated numeric array
num_array = vertcat(M{:})

%// Reshape and permute the numeric array such that the index to be used
%// for indexing data from different cells ends up as the final dimension
num_array = permute(reshape(num_array,size_num_arr),perm_dim)
num_array = permute(num_array,[p_matrix numel(size_cell)+1])

%// Save the numeric array as a cell array with each block from
%// thus obtained numeric array from its first to the second last dimension 
%// forming each cell
size_num_arr2 = size(num_array)
size_num_arr2c = num2cell(size_num_arr2(1:end-1))
M = squeeze(mat2cell(num_array,size_num_arr2c{:},ones(1,num_cells)))
```

Some quick tests show that `mat2cell` would prove to be the bottleneck, so if you don't mind indexing into the intermediate numeric array variable `num_array` and use it's last dimension for an equivalent indexing into M, then this approach could be useful.

Now, another approach if you would like to preserve the cell format would be with `arrayfun`, assuming each cell of `M` to be a `4D` numeric array -

```
M = arrayfun(@(x) num_array(:,:,:,:,x),1:N,'Uniform',0)
```

This seems to perform much better than with `mat2cell` in terms of performance.

Please note that `arrayfun` isn't a vectorized solution as most certainly it uses loops behind-the-scenes and seems like `mat2cell` is using for loops inside its source code, so please do keep all these issues in mind.